# How to run cross-sectional regressions for each industry and year?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am an R-beginner and having a problem with how to have a solution in R to run cross-sectional regression within each industry by year with the following sample like this:

```
Firm   Industry    Year  Var1    Var2    Var3
ABC    Materials   2001   ...     ...     ...
ABC    Materials   2002   ...     ...     ...
ABC    Materials   2003   ...     ...     ...
XYZ    Financial   2001   ...     ...     ...
XYZ    Financial   2002   ...     ...     ...
XYZ    Financial   2003   ...     ...     ...
```

My model is like this: Var1 ~ Var2 + Var3

I appreciate anyone for any comments. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Hoang, if you need a simple linear regression R can for each of these groups Hadley example is beutiful to say the least. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html

If you need to do panel data analysis try to read https://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101R.pdf

If you get any specifc problem try to decide if it is a statistics problem and ask in Cross Validadeted or an R problem and ask it here.

Good Luck.